# Is threads calling back to creating thread thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I don't like this code but I always get confused with threads so wanted someone else's input before I suggest a change; Is this thread safe (Psuedo code though based on C#):

```
class ThreadCreator
{
    private AnObject obj = new AnObject();
    public ThreadCreator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            ThingToThread th = new ThingToThread();//don't care about losing ref to th for this question
            th.sendMsg = this.getMessage;
            Thread t = new Thread(th.doThing);
            t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            t.Start();
        }
    }

    public void getMessage( string stuff )
    {
        ...
        obj.DoThing(stuff);
        ...
    }
}

class ThingToThread
{
    public delegate void sendMsg(string stuff);

    public void doThing()
    {
        ...
        this.sendMsg("ohh that's interesting");
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `AnObject.DoThing` advertised as being thread-safe?

Comment: @Brian: No. It looks ok but the whole getMessage function does too much for me to be sure (without spending a considerable amount of time looking). It also uses several components, some of which are generic and likely to be changed without realising they need to be thread safe... I don't like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't calling back to the any other thread.

Your code will execute the delegate on the new thread, just like any other function call.

If `getMessage` is not thread-safe, your code will break.

Comment: I guess my worry is that obj.DoThing needs to be thread safe too, and everything that calls etc. I'm not sure how maintainable this is...

Answer (score 0):

Your example isn't thread safe, if you wanted thread-safety I would very much advise using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) for executing in a new thread, but posting messages back to the main thread.

For example:

```
class ThreadCreator
{
    private AnObject obj = new AnObject();
    public ThreadCreator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            ThingToThread th = new ThingToThread();

            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.DoWork += th.DoWork;
            worker.ProgressChanged += WorkerProgressChanged;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    private void WorkerProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string stuff = e.UserState as string;
        obj.DoThing(stuff);
    }
}
```

And your ThingToThread DoWork method would look like:

```
public void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    worker.ReportProgress(50, "Half way there");

    worker.ReportProgress(100, "Finished");
}
```

Comment: This is old code, I don't think you finished your final sentence, guessing you want to say OK...

Comment: Hi @Patrick, I've pasted a code sample, of utilising the `BackgroundWorker` just in case you do wish to change the way the code works. If you are using .NET 1/1.1 I do apologise, but 2.0 and afterwards all support the `BackgroundWorker`.